# UIRefreshControl Below the TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have implemented UIRefreshControl on a TableView in my application. It works fine while being on the top of the table. However, I want the user to pull the tableview up till the end point of the current table view list and then the user pulls the tableview upwards and release it to reload the data.

Is this possible with UIRefreshControl?

Answer (score 1):

There is no frame property for `UIRefreshControl`, however, if you set the frame anyway, you can successfully "place it" wherever you like but the TableView Controller automatically moves it to the top during any kind of scrolling.

From the [`UITableViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007523-CH3-SW6) docs:

> ... a refresh control to this property adds the control to the
>   view controller’s associated interface. You do not need to set the
>   frame of the refresh control before associating it with the view
>   controller. **The view controller updates the control’s height and width
>   and sets its position appropriately.**